# Default value gets stored in another column based on value selected from LOV

Tags: oracle-adf

Table-`Items`

Columns-Order_Type

```
               (Sales,
               Return,
               Defective)
```

Order_Type_Id(1,2,3) 
i.e            1-Sales,
               2-Return,
               3-Defective

VO has Transient attribute-OrderType which has an LOV showing Order_Type.
Based on selected Order_Type, Order_Type_Id should get stored in Order_Type_Id column

```
public Number getOrder_Type_Id() {
    String orderType = null;
    Number orderNumber = null;
    if (getOrderType() != null) {
        orderType = getOrderType();
        if (orderType.equals("Sales")) {
            orderNumber = new oracle.jbo.domain.Number(2);
        } else if (orderType.equals("Return")) {
            orderNumber = new oracle.jbo.domain.Number(3);
        } else if (orderType.equals("Defective")) {
            orderNumber = new oracle.jbo.domain.Number(4);
        }
        this.setOrder_Type_Id(orderNumber);
    }
```

Comment: can you update your question with viewobject xml source

Comment: So what's happening? Hows your LOV is populated? All the values are static list or coming from any column? Does order_type_id has any default value?

Comment: OrderType has LOV whose values comes from Order_Type in Items table column . It displays Order_Type.Order_Type_Id does not have default value.I used the above code but it displays value 2 every time even if it's not Sales order

Comment: Have you tried to print getOrderType() as SOP?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Following code worked.**
Writing following code in Order_Type_Id:

```
public Number Order_Type_Id()
{ 
String orderType=null;
Number orderNumber=null;
if(getOrder_Type()!=null){
orderType=getOrder_Type();
if(orderType.equals("Sales")){
orderNumber=new oracle.jbo.domain.Number(2);
}
else if(orderType.equals("Defective")){
orderNumber=new oracle.jbo.domain.Number(3);
return orderNumber;
}
else
{
return (Number)getAttributeInternal(Order_Type_Id);}
}
}
```

In Order_Type_Id attribute add dependency or Order_Type

Comment: If the solution is working please edit the answer properly. So person should understand that it's an answer.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming LOV VO is also from Query not from static list :

It is developed in ADF 11g

OrderTypeLOVVO :

```
  order_type_id  - back-end stored column
  order_type_desc - display column
```

BaseOrderVO

```
OrderTypeId - transient attribute - LOV - OrderTypeLOVVO 
OrderTypeDesc - transient attribute - OutputText column with default value - 1
```

orderTypeId

```
  - Make autoSubmit property true in both places in VO and in jsff page ( drop it as select one choice) .
  - OrderTypeId value will be bindings.orderTypeId.inputValue

  -  Shuffle the dependent attribute Order_type_desc from left to right in dependecies component of VO.
```

OrderTypeDesc

```
  Make default value as 1 and in jsff page set partial trigger dependent of orderTypeId after dropping it as output label.
  Make OrderTypeDesc value attribute as bindings.orderTypeId.attributeValue
```

We need to make **OrderTypeDesc** value as **orderTypeId.attributeValu**e because when you select OrderTypeId as sales (this is **inputValue**), so backend value (id) is 1. so **attributeValue** will get the id of the selected value in LOV.

Same works with static list VO too.

**As per your requirement, In programatically,**

I have created a method on value change listener of LOV,

`changeValue()` is the method in bean class.

```
public void changeValue(ValueChangeEvent valueChangeEvent) {
    AppModuleImpl module = getApp(); // creating appModuleImpl class object
    //definition for getApp() is given below.

    item_desc = module.assignValue(valueChangeEvent.getNewValue().toString());
    // This item_desc value is declared globally.

    //assignValue method of AppModuleClass is given below
    bind_item_desc.setValue(item_desc);
    AdfFacesContext adfFacesContext = AdfFacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
    adfFacesContext.addPartialTarget(bind_item_desc);
     // bind_item_desc is the binding attribute of output label which needs to be refreshed.
    // Add event code here...
}
public static AppModuleImpl getApp() {
    return (AppModuleImpl)Configuration.
            createRootApplicationModule(
            "Model.AppModule", // where your module is stored
            "AppModuleShared"); // chosen configuration
}
```

Here `Model.AppModule` is the location of AppModule.

`assingValue()` of AppModuleClass where it will assign the value according to the selected value in LOV.

```
public String assignValue(String value)
{
    String item_desc=null;
    System.out.println("Changed value " + value);
    if(value.equals("Sales"))
    {
    item_desc="14";
    }
    return item_desc;
}
```

In assignValue, Parameter is value which will be input from bean class (a selected value from LOV) and returning the String parameter which you will be needed back again in bean class.

So when you select a value in LOV, it will trigger the value change listener method (changeValue()) and will navigate to AppModule . In AppModule , value will be assigned and come back to Bean class.

But it will not reflect untill, you will not refresh the page component.

```
<af:selectOneChoice value="#{bindings.item_id_lov.inputValue}"
                    label="item for lov"
                    required="#{bindings.item_id_lov.hints.mandatory}"
                    shortDesc="#{bindings.item_id_lov.hints.tooltip}"
                    id="soc4" autoSubmit="true"
                    valueChangeListener="#{bean1.changeValue}">
  <f:selectItems value="#{bindings.item_id_lov.items}" id="si4"/>
</af:selectOneChoice>
```

Here value change listener is called in SelectOneChoice and autoSubmit is true.

```
<af:panelLabelAndMessage label="item description"
                         id="plam1" partialTriggers="soc4">
  <af:outputFormatted value="#{bean1.item_desc}" binding="#{bean1.bind_item_desc}"
                      id="of1"/>
</af:panelLabelAndMessage>
```

Here , in `value` attribute `item_desc` is assigned (which is declared in bean). Also binding got created for the output label. PartialTrigger is assigned of LOV as outputLabel is dependent on LOV.

Comment: You want it programatically?

Comment: I wanted to check on AM first.I added above code in RowImpl class..Yes wanted it programatically..

Comment: I have updated the answer with programmatic way too.